# Bootstrap vertical grid's side by side

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm finding it hard to explain what i'm trying to do but hopefully it makes sense. I'm creating two bootstrap grids to hold expanding text boxes. Like the screenshot below;

[What i'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr771.png)

However with the code i'm using it appears like below;

[The box dropping down on the right side causes the left side to drop down even though they are in seperate rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek6pw.png)

My Code is below.

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-lg-6">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12"></div>
<div class="col-lg-12"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col col-lg-6">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12"></div>
<div class="col-lg-12"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How should I make this work correctly?

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: Check the images. When I click the drop down box on the left it opens to display the text but the grid on the left also drops down. I want to be able to open dropdowns without affecting the other side of the grid, if that makes sense? I'm not sure how I should arrange the grids.

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't work, could you give us more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- left column -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Collapsible Item #1
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="card-body">
            Text 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mt-3">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              Collapsible Item #3
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
          <div class="card-body">
            Text 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- right column -->
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Item #2
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
          <div class="card-body">
            Text
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mt-3">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingFour">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
              Collapsible Item #4
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
          <div class="card-body">
            Text
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```